# How can I know whether a police escort is required in a given area of Pakistan?

Tags: safety, regulations, pakistan

I have read that a police escort might be needed/required in some areas of Pakistan. E.g. https://www.thebrokebackpacker.com/is-pakistan-safe/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190719035836/https://www.thebrokebackpacker.com/is-pakistan-safe/)):

> you might have to travel with an armed police escort in some places.

How can I know whether a police escort is required in a given area of Pakistan, if possible, ahead of time (before entering the area)?

Answer (score 2):

The [UK Foreign Office](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/pakistan/safety-and-security) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190720214510/https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/pakistan/safety-and-security)) advises this:

> When travelling in Pakistan, you or your travel company should contact
>   the local authorities of your destination in advance to check the
>   local security situation. They may arrange police protection as
>   necessary and will advise whether you need a No Objection Certificate
>   issued by the Pakistani Ministry of Interior.

Basically, call ahead to the Police in the place you want to get to.

Comment: @Franck Just curious: why did you think the link needed a mirror?

Comment: in case content changes or moves to a different page. Over 10% of links on stack overflow are 404 :/

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt In this case wouldn't up-to-date information be preferred over an outdated mirrored link? Based on the link itself I wouldn't expect the link to change in the (near) future anyway.

Comment: Wouldn't the likely outcome of an inquiry be "you shouldn't go to X without a police escort, but we won't be providing one unless you give us a very good reason why we would want you at X, so you should consider staying away"?

Comment: @gnasher729 That might be one outcome, but it's purely speculative. If there was really an objection I'd expect the No Objection Certificate to be withheld.